Mi bot de discord reproduce audio alojado localmente, pero al subirlo a una vps, no reproduce nada
estoy intentando reproducir audio con mi bot mediante discordjs/voice. Cuando ejecuto mi bot localmente, todo funciona bien y lo reproduce, pero al subirlo a mi vps que tengo, con sistema ubuntu, el bot entra al canal de voz pero no reproduce nada, y en la consola no me tira ningún error. Tengo todas las dependencias instaladas que están en mi máquina local en la vps.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Sin algo que probar va a ser imposible ayudarte...
